# Window background is clipped by status bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am setting image as window background:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_window</item>   
</style>
```

It works for tablets and fullscreen windows:

[image]

but on the handset it is clipped by status bar:

[image]

Is this the way things work? How do I avoid it? Of course, I could set the background for each layout, but I want to know if this the only way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

My solution to this problem (at least for phones) was to create a xml drawable with the statusbar height as the top offset

e.g. drawable/window_background.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="25dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/some_background" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This will not work, if the status bar is on the bottom though.

EDIT: edited the answer to use a single xml drawable, as sugested by Aleksejs Mjaliks

Comment: yes, I need my app to run both on tablets and phones. But thanks for the idea anyway.

Comment: Just had another idea. Instead of diffrent xmls for each statusbar size, we could define a dimention for this height in the diffrent values folders e.g. and in values-sw720dp-land this could be 0dp. Or we could put another window_background.xml in drawable-swxxx folders for tablets.

Comment: Some 7" tablets (e.g. Galaxy Tab) can have status bar at the top or at the bottom of the screen. I'm not sure, but looks like it depends on the Android version installed.

Comment: Use `dp`: `android:top="25dp"`

Answer (score 2):

Try it in the following way..

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_window</item>   
</style>
```

:)

Comment: That's definitely an option, but status bar will be inaccesible on the phones, and I don't want that to happen.

Comment: Another option is to set the background image as the main layout background.

Comment: I mentioned this approach in my question.